# React CORS problem in JS but returns 200 and content in body in network tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors

Request to server returns 200 with wanted content in the browser network tab, but in JavaScript the response is type cors. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Comment: Unfortunately not. The client can get the response from the server, but when the body is read it's a cors error

Comment: That still sounds like a duplicate. You might want to quote the full error message.

Comment: I get 200 from the request in my browser though Quentin

Comment: "I get 200 from the request in my browser though Quentin" — So what? Does the error message claim you didn't get a 200 OK status? Does the answer to the question I referenced say that CORS errors are always accompanied by non-200 status codes? (it doesn't).

Comment: Sorry, I think there has been a misunderstanding, I meant to say, I get a 200 response with the content I want from the server in the network tab (when the frontend is calling the backend). I'm confused as to why the network tab doesn't have a cors error

Comment: The question I referenced in my initial comment explains that. There's a big heading marked "Why the Same Origin Policy only applies to JavaScript in a web page"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't a cors problem after all. The returned body is an image and was being read as json